# Is there any mistake in new Function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have read the [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). So I try to transform **function declaration** into **function expression** by **new Function**. But, I am stuck in the code below:

```
function Foo(name, age) {
    Foo.prototype.name = name;
    Foo.prototype.age  = age;
}
var foo = new Foo(1,2); // this is ok
console.log(Foo.prototype.hasOwnProperty('name'));
console.log(foo.hasOwnProperty('name'));
```

However there is an error after transformation:

```js
var Foo = new Function(['name', 'age'], 'Foo.prototype.name=name;Foo.prototype.age=age;');
var foo = new Foo(1,2); // error: Foo is not defined 
console.log(Foo.prototype.hasOwnProperty('name'));
console.log(foo.hasOwnProperty('name'));
```

Is there any mistake? Any answer is helpful.

The code is right in my chrome browser. However it makes an error on platform:

- nodejs: 6.10.0
- win7 64bit

Comment: You can log Foo and see if it is a function

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: None of what you wrote makes any sense...

Comment: You are missing a closing ")" on the first line. Or maybe you meant that. Wacky code.

Comment: @ILikeToMoveItMoveIt Yes, It is a function object.

Comment: @Pointy I am just learning the Prototype Chain.

Comment: @LiverpoolCoder which ')' exactly? You can write an answer to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: The second code block works fine for me as shown, so I'm voting to close the question as off-topic because there isn't enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @nnnnnn I use nodejs version v6.10.0 to run code by win64 platform instead of console of browser. Is there any difference?

Comment: I don't know much about Node. Please [edit] the question to provide that detail. I only tested in Chrome, but I guess that code works for you too in the browser?

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, browser is ok. Thank you for pointing out this.

Comment: var Foo = new Function(['name', 'age'], 'Foo.prototype.name=name;Foo.prototype.age=age;');
   
    console.log(Foo.prototype.hasOwnProperty('name'));
     var foo = new Foo(1,2); // error: Foo is not defined 
    console.log(Foo.prototype.hasOwnProperty('name'));
    console.log(foo.hasOwnProperty('name'));

This returns false true false  :D

Comment: One issue will be scope. The string of code for a `new Function()` is evaluated in the global scope rather than within the closure/module scope that Node.js creates for variables in each file. So, it could find `global.Foo`, but not `var Foo`.

Comment: what the matter to change prototype in constructor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `var Foo` isn't defined where the `Function` can reach it, at least not while using Node.

When you create a function from a string using the `new Function()` constructor, the function only has access to the global scope, regardless of where it's created.

And, when within a Node module, `var Foo` and `var foo` aren't global variables. They're local variables that exists only within the current file/module, within a "module" scope.

```
var bar = 'bar';
console.log(bar);        // function
console.log(global.bar); // undefined
```

To allow the `new Function()` to access `Foo`, you'll have to define the latter as a global variable (or a property of the `global` object).

```
global.Foo = new Function(['name', 'age'], 'Foo.prototype.name=name;Foo.prototype.age=age;');
var foo = new Foo(1,2);
// ...
```

> Though, you should be aware that modifying the global scope/object like this is generally frowned upon in Node, since this goes against its intent/design of using isolated modules.

---

Though, to define the function from an expression, you don't need to use the `Function` constructor. You can instead [place the declaration where an *Expression* is expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-function-declaration-syntax-var-fn-function-vs-function-fn), such as after an assignment operator.

```
var Foo = function (name, age) {
    Foo.prototype.name = name;
    Foo.prototype.age  = age;
};
var foo = new Foo(1,2); // this is ok
// ...
```